# Was Purim the greatest miracle?

Tags: purim, yetziat-mitzrayim

I have seen in multiple places such as [The Maharal](https://www.sefaria.org/Ohr_Chadash%2C_Preface?vhe=Ohr_Chadash,_with_footnotes_and_annotations_by_Rabbi_Yehoshua_D._Hartman,_Machon_Yerushalyim,_2014&lang=bi#:%7E:text=%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A9%20%D7%96%D7%94%2C%20%D7%9B%D7%99%20%D7%99%D7%A9%20%D7%9C%D7%9A%20%D7%9C%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%20%D7%9E%D7%9F%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%92%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%94%20%D7%94%D7%96%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%A9%D7%94%D7%92%D7%99%D7%A2%20%D7%9C%D7%94%D7%9D%20%D7%91%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%20%D7%94%D7%9E%D7%9F%20%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA%D7%A8%20%D7%9E%D7%9B%D7%9C%20%D7%94%D7%A6%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA) that the circumstances the jews of purim were in were worse then any other predicament they experienced in the past. (Including Egypt).

Is it written anywhere that the *miracle* of purim was greater than any previous miracle or redemption, such as the exodus? Something similar to [this](https://torah.org/purim/the-miracle-of-jewish-survival/#:%7E:text=If%20we%20look,dustbin%20of%20history.), but with a source.

Comment: How does one evaluate the size of a miracle?

Comment: @DoubleAA Thats not for me to judge, possibly someone of greater stature then i has mentioned it somewhere, that is what i am looking for. Any source that mentions that the miracle of Purim was greater then any previous.  (A possible way to evaluate the greatness can be how overt the miracle was, such as the open and beyond nature miracle of Sea Splitting Vs the miracle of purm which was enclothed within nature)

Comment: Do you mean the actual miracle or the salvation it resulted in? I'm pretty sure chassidus discusses how Purim in a certain respect is a greater miracle *because* it's enclothed in nature. But it's one of those perspectives that might change with the season, i.e., a Chanukah maamar might explain why Chanukah is still greater.